# Kendo Dialog Max Length

Tags: kendo-ui

I am attempting to use a Kendo Dialog for a basic prompt for user input.

Here is my code (similar to the [instructions](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/layout/dialog/how-to/customize-predefined-dialogs) given by Telerik):

```js
return $("<div></div>").kendoPrompt({
   title: "Enter Reason",
   content: "Enter a reason for your action",
   width: 400
}).data("kendoPrompt").open().result;
```

What I need is to set a maximum input length (400 characters) on the generated text box. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround, first hide default input, then on content add kendo template. Promise will receive inputted data.

Something like this:

```
<style>
   .k-prompt-container .k-textbox {
      display: none;
   }
</style>
```

---

```
<button id="promptBtn" class="k-button">myprompt</button>   
<script id="test" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <p>Please enter text, max 10 length</p>
    <input class="k-textbox" maxlength="10"/>
</script>
```

---

```
$('#promptBtn').on('click', function () {
    window.myPrompt().then(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }, function () {
        console.log('cancel');
    })
});

function myPrompt() {
    return $('<div></div>').kendoPrompt({
        title: 'Kendo prompt',
        value: '',
        content: kendo.template($('#test').html()),
    }).getKendoPrompt().open().result;
}
```

Example: [Kendo custom prompt](https://dojo.telerik.com/isogEruN)